# How to make two arrays match by filling in zeroes?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In Javascript I'm grabbing the results here, and putting them into two variables: ticks and s1.

```
var viewModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
var items = viewModel.Date1;
var items2 = viewModel.Date2;
var newCount;
var ticks = [];
var s1 = [];
var colors = [];
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {            
    newCount = items[i].theCount / items2[i].theCount * 100;
    ticks.push(items[i].theCycle);
    s1.push(newCount);
    if (newCount < 98)
        colors.push("#FF2F2F");
    else
        colors.push("#00749F");
}
```

The results are this:

How many where where b.active_serv != 0 - items

```
Cycle   Count
1       823
6       530
7       475
9       962
10      591
11      121
13      751
15      716
50      133
100     39
```

The total of them all (without that where clause) -items2

```
Cycle   Count
1       833
6       532
7       492
9       967
10      611
11      121
13      767
14      37
15      816
16      71
19      3
21      101
23      11
50      133
100     39
```

As you see, there are more cycles in the total (items2) then in b.active_serv != 0 (items). I need to fix items to match items2 because to get percentages I'm doing:

```
newCount = items[i].theCount / items2[i].theCount * 100;
```

How do I go through all of variable items , and add a zero in the correct positions in that array for if the cycle numbers do not match (or missing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If item is an array of `row` objects with `theCycle` and `theCount` members, this returns an array of rows in which items that don't have a matching `theCycle` member in `item2` are replaced by `{theCycle:0, theCount:0}`

```
items = items2.map( row => 
                       //is there a matching row in items?
                       items.filter( r => r.theCycle == row.theCycle).length ==  0 ? 
                      //if not, fill with zeros
                      {theCycle:0, theCount:0} : 
                      //if there is, return the items' row
                      items.filter( r => r.theCycle == row.theCycle)[0] );
```

Of course, this assumes that `r.theCycle` is a unique identifier.

For example, if we had these two arrays:

```
var items = [{theCycle:2, theCount:2}, {theCycle:1, theCount:1}];
var items2 = [{theCycle:2, theCount:2}, {theCycle:1, theCount:1}, {theCycle:3, theCount:3} ];
```

We should obtain the following resutl:

```
[{theCycle:2,theCount:2},{theCycle:1,theCount:1},{theCycle:0,theCount:0}]
```

Where the third nonexisting object in `items` is replaced by zeros.